# Webpack ContextReplacementPlugin get packages from node_modules

Tags: node.js, webpack

We are trying to make a webpack bundle, which will include all of our dependencies inside a single bundle.

There is a specific package, which has dynamic requires from node_modules, and webpack can't resolve the packages correctly at compile time.

The code that generates the error is:

```js
// config.middlewares is a list of packages inside node_modules
Object.keys(config.middlewares).forEach(function (moduleName) {
  var pkg = require(moduleName)
  var alias = config.middlewares[moduleName]
  helmet[alias] = pkg
})
```

Webpack compiles it into:

```js
Object.keys(config.middlewares).forEach(function (moduleName) {
  var pkg = !(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \".\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())
  var alias = config.middlewares[moduleName]
  helmet[alias] = pkg
})
```

So we tried using Webpack's ContextReplacementPlugin, but whatever we tried we couldn't configure it to change the context to fetch a file from node_modules.

Somethings we tried (we first tried to just get one specific package, called hsts):

````js
new ContextReplacementPlugin(/helmet.*/, /\.\.\/hsts/)
new ContextReplacementPlugin(/helmet.*/, /\.\/\.\.\/hsts/)
new ContextReplacementPlugin(/helmet.*/, /\.\/\.\.\/hsts\/index\.js/)
```
````

Comment: any luck with this in the end? I'm facing a similar issue...